# scrolling only parts of the page while making them cover the entire screen

Tags: html, css

[image]

What is the best way of achieving this?

```
<div class=container>
 <div class=topbar></div>
 <div class=leftbar></div>
 <div class=content-wrap>
  <div class=content-hearer></div>
  <div class=content></div>
  <div class=content-footer></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.body .head{margin:0; height:100%}
.container{height:100%}
.topbar{width:100%; height:30px}
.leftbar {width: 50px; height: 100%; overflow: auto; float: left}
.content-wrap{height: 100%; overflow: auto; float: left}
.content-header{height:30px}
.content{height:100%; overflow:auto}
.content-footer{height:35px}
```

I Want to cover the entire page...and only want left bar and content to scroll when required else cover the remaining space. All other things are fixed

Comment: What about `overflow: scroll;`?

Comment: @Algosub how would `overflow:scroll` possibly be of any help? Can you clarify please?

Comment: Add `overflow:auto` in css for `.content`..this will make just the content div scrollable..try it..

Comment: Do you want the left bar and content scroll at *the same time* or *independent* of each other?

Comment: you can do this using calc() http://jsfiddle.net/psvpkjcz/

Comment: independent of each other...
I have actually tried multiple ways including display:table. It fails when there is a scroll and make the entire page scroll. So thought maybe I will just ask how the experience ppl will do it. I have seen similar questions asked multiple times where people have issues with making a div cover the empty space, but havent found where it covers the empty space at the same time scrolls when overflows

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan look at Vitorino Fernandes answer.

Comment: @Algosub rather, take a look at my answer ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/sededu/2/edit)***

**Pure old-school CSS:** <sup>(*no CSS3*)</sup>

```css
*{margin:0;}
html, body{
  height:100%;
}
#top{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:50px; /* See #wrapper bottom value */
  background:#ddd;
}
#wrapper{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  bottom:0;
  top:50px; /* compensate #top height */ 
}
#left{
  position:absolute;
  background: #3BB3C3;
  height:100%;
  width:150px;   /* See #right left value */
  overflow:auto; /* make scrollable if content overflows */
}
#right{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  left:150px; /* compensate #left width */
  bottom:0;
  height:100%;
  background:#EE9B69;
}
#header{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;   /* (100% cause of fixed pos) */
  height:30px;  /* see #page top value */
  background:#F8C301;
}
#page{
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;    /* header height */
  bottom:30px; /* bottom height */
  width:100%;
  overflow-y:scroll;
} 
#footer{
  background:#B8DC7C;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%; /* (100% cause of fixed) */
  bottom:0;
  height:30px; /* see #page bottom value */
}

/* DEMO ONLY */
p.long{
  height:1500px;
  border-left:5px dotted #000;
}
```

```html
<div id=top>TOP</div>

<div id=wrapper>
  
  <div id=left>
    LEFT<p class=long>Long content</p>--END!
  </div>

  <div id=right>
    <div id=header>HEADER</div>
    <div id=page>
      ARTICLE CONTENT<p class=long>Long content test</p>--END!
    </article>
    <div id=footer>FOOTER</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @calvin12 edited my answer to make it crossbrowser (without CSS3)

Comment: This doesnt work...if I add a lot of text to leftbar, the entire page scrolls

Comment: No..just dont delete the previous example :)..Please add that too

Comment: @calvin12 created a better example that will handle the scrolling you requested but also work in IE8 and modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body,
.container {
  height: 100%;
}
.topbar {
  background: grey;
  height: 40px;
}
.leftbar {
  background: blue;
  width: 30%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.content-wrap {
  background: red;
  width: 70%;
}
.leftbar,
.content-wrap {
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  float: left;
}
.content-hearer {
  height: 40px;
  background: yellow;
}
.content-footer {
  height: 40px;
  background: green;
}
.content {
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  background: orange;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="topbar"></div>
  <div class="leftbar">Fusce pharetra convallis urna. Etiam rhoncus. Phasellus volutpat, metus eget egestas mollis, lacus lacus blandit dui, id egestas quam mauris ut lacus. Quisque libero metus, condimentum nec, tempor a, commodo mollis, magna. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor
    eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Suspendisse nisl elit, rhoncus eget, elementum ac, condimentum eget, diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit
    erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Fusce a quam. Praesent nonummy mi in odio. Fusce egestas elit eget lorem. Fusce ac felis sit amet ligula pharetra condimentum. Pellentesque dapibus hendrerit tortor. Suspendisse pulvinar, augue
    ac venenatis condimentum, sem libero volutpat nibh, nec pellentesque velit pede quis nunc. Praesent porttitor, nulla vitae posuere iaculis, arcu nisl dignissim dolor, a pretium mi sem ut ipsum. Fusce convallis metus id felis luctus adipiscing. Vivamus
    elementum semper nisi. Nullam vel sem. Nullam sagittis. Vivamus laoreet. Aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <div class="content-hearer"></div>
    <div class="content">Fusce pharetra convallis urna. Etiam rhoncus. Phasellus volutpat, metus eget egestas mollis, lacus lacus blandit dui, id egestas quam mauris ut lacus. Quisque libero metus, condimentum nec, tempor a, commodo mollis, magna. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor
      eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Suspendisse nisl elit, rhoncus eget, elementum ac, condimentum eget, diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit
      erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Fusce a quam. Praesent nonummy mi in odio. Fusce egestas elit eget lorem. Fusce ac felis sit amet ligula pharetra condimentum. Pellentesque dapibus hendrerit tortor. Suspendisse pulvinar, augue
      ac venenatis condimentum, sem libero volutpat nibh, nec pellentesque velit pede quis nunc. Praesent porttitor, nulla vitae posuere iaculis, arcu nisl dignissim dolor, a pretium mi sem ut ipsum. Fusce convallis metus id felis luctus adipiscing. Vivamus
      elementum semper nisi. Nullam vel sem. Nullam sagittis. Vivamus laoreet. Aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
    <div class="content-footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: somehow this makes content to scroll horizontally

Comment: which browser ? which content?

Comment: tried in the jsfiddle...content inside the content div

Comment: if you are talking about `work-break` then add this `word-break:break-word;` http://jsfiddle.net/k03Lyug5/1/

Comment: @calvin12 have you tested this in IE8?